# Create a Airport Database with API Access

Tags: javascript, json

I'm looking to create a database which I can access without api keys using a link. Essentially, I"m looking to copy this exact system: http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?callback=?&q=New except I'd like to replace the results with Airport codes and names which I have. Anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Maybe it will help if I clarify further. I am using typeahead and in my custom.js file I have the following which I need to update to use my own dataset but I"m clueless on how to do this.

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
hint: true,
highlight: true,
minLength: 3,
limit: 8
}, {
source: function(q, cb) {
    return $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        url: 'http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?callback=?&q=' + q,
        chache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            var result = [];
            $.each(data, function(index, val) {
                result.push({
                    value: val
                });
            });
            cb(result);
        }
    });
}
```

});

Comment: do you want to create or consume at restful system?? your question its not clear

Comment: you're saying you want to create a database - what server-side stack are you planning on using? LAMP? Node.js / MongoDB? Azure / SQL Server?

Comment: @ncubica  My apologies, I'm not sure myself what I need. From my research it looks like I need to consume a restful system. I don't know where to start. How do I create a resftul system that will allow me to query it and it will show only matching results like the link above?

Comment: @SergeyK Is it possible to use an existing mysql server to query it without logging in or an api key, just with the url? That would be super cool since that's something I know how to setup.

Comment: Sorry man if you dont describe properly your problem its really complicate it for us to help you.

Comment: @ncubica I know, I really am not sure what I am asking. Can I ask a very basic question. Where can I create a database that I can access it with a URL link and a query. That's really what I"m asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your comments:

what you want to know are three questions assuming you are gonna work with php and mysql since is  easy and basic way to start with web development (imho):

you need to know:

1. Tutorial of how to create a database with mysql
2. How to connect mysql with php
3. How to response a json with php
4. How to make a ajax request
   to a php server with javascript

To be honest man this is a lot to learn and if you are starting with web development I totally suggest you going for the basic first. What you are trying to build at the end is a Restful system, there a lot of frameworks and ways to do this, via Web Api C#, or http://www.slimframework.com/
as example, but again you question is too abroad and not too clear, Im trying to help you because in one moment I started with all this questions, I googled for a tutorials in web development I hope some will work for you https://www.odesk.com/blog/2014/03/10-best-web-development-tutorials-beginners/

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed comment, I am interested in learning these technologies and your guidance is very much appreciated. I actually started following your advice and reading up on how to create a database with mysql... and the Odesk link has many useful links. Thanks again!